# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I am using XIB and trying to insert data into core data while i get notification and i am doing this in following method.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(
UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    [arr_message addObject:data];
    NSMutableArray *arr_insert_data = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   _context=[self managedObjectContext];
   [arr_insert_data addObject:local_data];
   [mainViewController insertDiscusioninLocalDB:arr_message];
}

-(void)insertDiscusioninLocalDB :(NSMutableArray*)arr_msg
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Discusion_data" inManagedObjectContext:app.context];// BREAKS HERE
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [request setEntity:entity];
}
```

Comment: `Discusion_data` is correct entity name?

Comment: yup thats the correct name

Comment: What are you doing with `arr_msg`? you are not using it.

Comment: just inserting the content of arr_msg(NSMutableArray) into cored data

Comment: put a break point and check `app.context` output.

Comment: it is null...!!

Comment: try replacing app.context with `[self managedObjectContext]`

Comment: Tried that our..!! still throwing same exception

Comment: Add some more code. Your `app.context` is nil, it needs to be assigned.

Comment: can you post your managed object core data methods from AppDelegate?

Comment: I initialized my AppDelegate instance(app) it woked